# Hebrew characters processed by HTML Tidy turn into gibberish

Tags: unicode, tidy, hebrew, htmltidy

I'm using HTML Tidy Online (http://infohound.net/tidy/) to tidy up some very old and messed up HTML file which contains some Hebrew characters. Whenever the page is processed by Tidy the output turns Hebrew characters into gibberish, even after changing encoding methods in the settings. Using different settings, I do manage to get the same output with the Hebrew characters as unicode entities. 
I Googled around for a possible solution but found none. 
I had a couple ideas in mind, but I'm not sure exactly how to approach them, if at all (maybe someone has a better solution).

> 1. I thought maybe I could (after processing the page) scan the page for unicode entities and replace them with the corresponding Hebrew characters (in a systematic way, of course).
> 2. Maybe I could take the HTML Tidy source code and modify it to output Hebrew characters appropriately. The problem with this is that I doubt I am knowledgeable enough to even get started on something like this.

Comment: Did you declare a charset in your HTML file?  If so, which one?  Exactly what do you mean by "gibberish"?  Show us a hex dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Document in UTF-8, containing unicode characters. HTML Tidy turned them into HTML entities. This in HTMLTIDY.CFG fixed it:

```
char-encoding: utf8
input-encoding: utf8
output-encoding: utf8
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The website http://infohound.net/tidy/ that you are using has a "Char encoding" clause at the bottom right. You need to choose utf-8, but first you need to make sure that the page is encoded in UTF-8 in your test editor. In Notepad++ for example, you can go to `Encoding > Convert to UTF-8 without BOM`.